# PHP how to display contents of another page from a function() using return

Tags: php, function, drupal

I need to display the content of another page from a function using return.
What is the best way to do this?

Say that I have `file.php`. In my script in another page, I want to call a function and return the contents of file.php.

For example:

```
myFunction() {
  $page = WHAT('file.php');
  return $page;
}
```

What to use in place of 'WHAT'? I've tried include, because it's what I know, but it doesn't work here.

EXTRA NOTES: This is used in a Drupal module. The admin theme / menu displays as normal if I use `$page = 'insert code here'; return $page;` - but not if I use `$page = include('file.php');` because the function doesn't even use the return when it sees `'include'`.

Comment: you need `file.php` source code ? try [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: include does return, otherwise it does output. output can be "returned" with output buffers. http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: I actually figured it out - but maybe I'll leave this in case someone else needs to know.

I used:

    $page = file_get_contents('file.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
     return $page;

Comment: @safarov - This was what I figured out immediately after posting the question! :) If you provide that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for code or content of file use: [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)
2. for instant result of another php page, you can try [ob_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean).

It will gather the output of the included file in memory and later you can gather the output to variable and clean the memory or just show the output directly.

like:

```
myFunction(){
   ob_start();
   include('file.php');
   $page = ob_get_clean();
   return $page;
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$page = file( 'file.php' );`
this will return an array containing each line of code.

```
function myFunction() {
  $page = file('file.php');
  return $page;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$myPage = myFunction();
foreach( $myPage  as $line => $code){
    echo $code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Curl to retrieve another page contents

```
 <?php
 myFunction()
{
  $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "file.php");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $output 
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function foo(){
   ob_start();
   include('file.php');
   $page = ob_get_clean();
   return $page;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want to return the Sourcecode of file.php without parsing it?
If yes, fopen and fread are your friends.

```
function yourFunction() {
    $filehandle = fopen('file.php', "r");
    $filecontent = fread($filehandle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($file_handle);

    return $filecontent;
}
```